# Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: while using hibernate template

Tags: spring, hibernate, templates

Getting this exception while using hibernate template in spring.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [roledesc, sapid, pass] [
        select u from Role as r left join r.users as u where u.sapid=:sapid and u.pass=:pass and r.roledesc=:roledesc
    ]
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$33.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:988)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$33.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 30 more
```

Here is the class where I'm trying to fetch the named query:

```
public class LoginDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl implements LoginDao {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoginDaoImpl.class);

    @Override
    public User loginCheck(User user, Role role) {
        LOGGER.debug("Inside validate user:" + user.getPass());

        user.setName("");

        List<User> employee = new ArrayList<User>();

        Query query = (Query) template.findByNamedQuery("findRoleforaUser");

        query.setString("sapid", user.getSapid());
        query.setString("pass", user.getPass());
        query.setString("roledesc", role.getRoledesc());
            employee = query.list();
            if(employee == null)
            {
                user.setName("");
            }

            else if(employee.isEmpty())
            {
                user.setName("");
            }


            else if (!(user.getPass().equals(employee.get(0).getPass())))

                LOGGER.info("No match found!");
            else {
                user.setName( employee.get(0).getName());
                LOGGER.debug("\nUser \"" + employee.get(0).getName()
                        + "\" found and login is successful ");

            }


                return user;
    }

}
```

And here is my .hbm file contents where the named query is defined:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM "D:\My HCL JEE Progs\CBA_Quiz\src\dtd\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hcl.cba.payments.domain.Role" table="roles">
        <id name="roleid" type="int" column="ROLEID" />
        <property name="roledesc" type="string" column="ROLEDESC" />
        <set name="users" cascade="all">
            <key column="roleid" />
            <one-to-many class="com.hcl.cba.payments.domain.User" />
        </set>
    </class>
    <query name="findRoleforaUser">
        <![CDATA[select u from Role as r left join r.users as u where u.sapid=:sapid and u.pass=:pass and r.roledesc=:roledesc]]>
    </query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

P.S:I tried running/accessing the query without hibernate template and it ran fine and I had set the variables the same way too:

> ```
>       Query query = session.findByNamedQuery("findRoleforaUser");
>       query.setString("sapid", user.getSapid());
>       query.setString("pass", user.getPass());
>       query.setString("roledesc", role.getRoledesc());            
>       employee =query.list();
> ```

Comment: Try with `query.setParameter()` instead of `query.setString()`

Comment: Same exception man! :( @Predrag Maric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
List<User> employees = new ArrayList<User>();
String[] paramNames = { "sapid", "pass", "roledesc" };
Object[] values = { user.getSapid(), user.getPass(), role.getRoledesc() };
employees = template.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("findRoleforaUser", paramNames, values);
```

Comment: `findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam` and `findByNamedQuery` should return a List. How can this be casted to a Query object?

Comment: Yea...it threw a class cast exception. I changed it to list and it worked. I'll edit the answer and accept it !

Comment: @wero You're right, I just copied from the question without paying attention to that. Thanks.